# When a predictor variable needs to be adjusted for technical covariates, is it better to add those covariates to the outcome model or use residuals?

Tags: multiple-regression, residuals, cox-model

When a predictor variable of one model needs to be adjusted for other measures before it is interpretable, is it better to fit a model for that predictor and then feed the residuals of that model into the outcome model? Or is it better to add the predictor-related measures into the outcome model?

As an example, say I am trying to investigate the relationship between whole blood WGS-derived mitochondrial DNA copy number and overall mortality.

Overall risk of mortality may need to be adjusted for some covariates, so I might write the model in R as something like this:

Model 1: `coxph(Surv(Follow_up_time, Death) ~ Age + Sex + Smoking_Status + BMI + Education + Ethnicity + mtDNA_CN, DF)`

However, because in this case mitochondrial DNA copy number is a tissue-specific relative value, it also needs to be adjusted for a number of technical covariates before it is interpretable, such as sex, age, white blood cell count, platelet count, blood cell subtype parameters, autosomal coverage, etc.

Model 2: `lm(mtDNA_CN ~ Age + Sex + WBC_n + Platelet_n + Blood_Parameters + Autosomal_Coverage, DF)`

Should I take the residuals of Model 2 and feed them into Model 1 instead of mtDNA_CN? e.g.

Model 3: `coxph(Surv(Follow_up_time, Death) ~ Age + Sex + Smoking_Status + BMI + Education + Ethnicity + Model_2_Residuals, DF)`

Or would it be better to simply add the technical covariates for mtDNA_CN into the survival model even though they may not themselves be related to mortality? e.g.

Model 4: `coxph(Surv(Follow_up_time, Death) ~ Age + Sex + WBC_n + Platelet_n + Blood_Parameters + Autosomal_Coverage + Smoking_Status + BMI + Education + Ethnicity + mtDNA_CN, DF)`

I have asked a few researchers I know and I've received conflicting answers. I have also seen similar questions asked in other threads, but was not able find one that answered this question specifically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model 4 provides the advantage of allowing for associations of `WBC_n`, `Platelet_n`, `Blood_Parameters` and `Autosomal_Coverage` with outcome beyond their association with `mtDNA_CN` (in Model 1) or its deviation from what would be predicted by Model 2 (in Model 3). In effect, Model 1 isn't substantively different from Model 3, except in interpretation. The disadvantage in moving to Model 4 is that you need to estimate more Cox coefficients and thus need a larger study size to avoid overfitting.

To illustrate, consider a set of simpler models only including `Age`, `mtDNA_CN` and `WBC_n`.

Then we have:

```
mod1a <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ Age + mtDNA_CN)
mod2a <- lm(mtDNA_CN ~ Age + WBC_n)
mod3a <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ Age + mod2resid)
mod4a <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ Age + mtDNA_CN + WBC_n)
```

Say that `mod2a` has an intercept `b0` and coefficients `bA` for `Age` and `bW` for `WBC_n`. Then:

```
mod2resid = mtDNA_CN - b0 - bA*Age - bW*WBC_n
```

and you can re-write `mod1a` and `mod3a` with flipped predictors associated with `mtDNA_CN`:

```
mod1a' <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ Age + mod2resid + b0 + bA*Age + bW*WBC_n)
mod3a' <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ Age +  mtDNA_CN - b0 - bA*Age - bW*WBC_n)
```

The point is that (with these simple linear associations) `mod1a` and `mod3a` aren't fundamentally different. You will get different estimates for the Cox coefficient for `Age` depending on your choice, as `Age` affects outcome both directly and via its association with `mtDNA_CN`. You don't see a coefficient for `WBC_n` in `mod1a` or `mod3a`; it provides a hidden fixed-coefficient offset due to its involvement in modeling the relation between `mtDNA_CN` and `mod2resid`.

What you lose in `mod1a` and `mod3a`, versus `mod4a`, is the ability to capture any association of `WBC_n` with outcome except insofar as it affects `mtDNA_CN` or `mod2resid`.

The above simplicity can disappear if there are nonlinear terms or interactions in the models, but the principles are the same. If you omit anything that both predicts `mtDNA_CN` and might be associated with outcome, you won't pick that up and you are risk of omitted-variable bias unless you include it in something like your Model 4.

For example, `mtDNA_CN` can come either from white cells or platelets (or even cell-free DNA, depending on how samples are prepared). The association of `mtDNA_CN` might well differ depending on how much is from white cells versus platelets. I also suspect that `WBC_n` and `Platelet_n` have additional associations with outcome beyond their role in determining `mtDNA_CN`. For example, `Platelet_n` could be related to cardiovascular deaths and `WBC_n` to deaths from immune dysfunction or infection. It would seem wise to include them, at least, explicitly in your model.

If there are purely technical factors affecting the values of `mtDNA_CN` (perhaps `Autosomal_Coverage`?) you should consider correcting the `mtDNA_CN` directly for them first.